The electrostatic potential due to a pair of oppositely charged infinite thin conducting plates

The electric field in region A and C (outside the pair of sheets) is 0. The electric field in region B (between the plates) is given by:
$$E = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon}.$$
The distance between the plates is d. Let us suppose the potential at infinity is $V$. Then the potential in regions A and C will be $V$ at all points as the field is zero at all the points. Similarly, in the plates, potential will be $V$.
But the potential difference between the plates is:
$$\Delta V = E d.$$
But It can also be given as:
$$\Delta V = V-V = 0.$$
How can this be possible?

The reason is that the potential at infinity cannot be defined in this case. To see why, observe that the relationship
$$V_A=V_C+Ed \tag{1}$$
is physically true and holds regardless of the choice of reference point. Since the electric field is zero in regions $A$ and $C$, the potentials are constant but different. So approaching infinity in regions $A$ and $C$ results in potentials $V_A$ and $V_C$ respectively. Therefore, the potential does not approach a single value at infinity but rather depends on the path chosen. In other words, the process
$$0 = \int_\infty^A\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} + \int_A^C\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}+\int_C^\infty\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}$$
fails as the first and last terms are path-dependent. It is impossible, as you have discovered, to define a potential at infinity without violating Eq. (1). Alternatively, this can be seen by using the fact that the potential of a single plate with respect to infinity is $\pm\infty$, arriving at a result of $\infty-\infty$ which is undefined.
As such, infinity cannot be used as a reference point for the potential so you have to use another point. Note that this issue only occurs with infinite charge distributions.

Thanks for the explanation. There is just one thing I don’t understand, What do you mean when you say path dependent?

@AadityaJain Suppose you start at the surface of the positive plate. If you approach infinity to the left (i.e. through region A), you get a different result than if you approach infinity to the right (through regions B and C), for the line integral of the electric field. The first path gives zero but the second path gives V.

Your assumption of a potential value of V in both A and C is incorrect. The potential difference between these regions is V.
For a finite system you can assume that the potential far away from the charges goes to zero. In this case the system is infinite and this intuitive assumption fails.

When we say that the plates are of infinite extent, we mean that  their linear dimensions, $l\ \text{and } l$, are far greater than the distance, $d$, between the plates and far greater than the distance, $p$, from the plates to any point, P, that is relevant. This is clearly the case ($l\gg p$) if P is anywhere between the plates. But if we consider points P that are an enormously long way from the plates, it will no longer be the case that $l\gg p$, so we can't assume zero field. The field will, of course be very small, but infinity is an awful long way away... The potential difference of either capacitor plate with respect to infinity can't, I believe, be calculated.

In Region C:
$$ V_C(x) = V(\infty) = V $$
In Region B:
$$ V_B(x) = V_C - (x-x_{BC})E $$
which leads to the potential in region A:
$$ V_A(x) = V + Ed = V(-\infty) $$
tl;dr infinity has a sign.

Given that there are no electric fields outside the plates those regions outside the plates must be equipotentials.
The difference between those two equipotential regions is the same as the potential difference between the two plates.
In terms a geographical feature you have a horizontal plain (region C), an incline of constant gradient (region B) and another horizontal plane (region A) higher than region C.
You can take your pick as to where you choose the zero of potential but there will always be a difference in height (potential) between regions C and A.
